# Have digitalWrite for a set amount of seconds inside if statement

Tags: arduino

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 connected to a pH sensor, that when the pH gets outside of a set pH range, will send a command through i2c to the raspi 3 that should control the motors that dispense acid or alkaline solution. How I have it set up, is that the raspi program calculates whether acid or base will be dispensed, and then how much time the motors should run. (for now its 1-9 seconds). Then it sends a number to the Arduino through i2c.

My problem is that the Arduino wants the motors running and not stop them. I tried the "delay(1000)" etc., but then the motors run for barely a second before turning off.

I have an LED set up that's green when the pH is in range, blue when it's under, and red when it's over.

I found out that delay() is not a good thing to use, so I tried implementing a millis() system, but that makes the motors run without stopping.

Here is the code. Keep in mind that I have barely any coding experience, and pretty much all of it is from other Stack Overflow questions.

```c
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04

//Apologies for this code. It was written by someone with almost no coding experience.

//colors are the led, the acidm & alkm are motors, l and r after it is left and right (cw vs ccw rotation)
int number = 0;
int state = 0;
int blue = 10;
int green = 9;
int red = 8;
int acidml = 5;
int acidmr = 4;
int alkml = 7;
int alkmr = 6;
int ph_lvl = 0;
int rtime = 0;
int mtime = 0;

//delay() seems to mess things up, so this will hopefully avoid it
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long second = 1000;

void setup() {
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600); // start serial for output

    // initialize i2c as slave
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

    // define callbacks for i2c communication
    Wire.onReceive(receiveData);

    Serial.println("Ready!");
}

void loop() {
    delay(100);
}

// callback for received data
void receiveData(int byteCount) {

    //this receives the number from the raspi
    while (Wire.available()) {
        number = Wire.read();
        Serial.print("data received: ");
        Serial.println(number);

        digitalWrite(alkmr, LOW);
        digitalWrite(acidmr, LOW);
        unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
        if (number > 20 && number < 30) {
            ph_lvl = 2;
        } else if (number < 20 && number > 10) {
            ph_lvl = 1;
        } else {
            ph_lvl = 0;
        }

        //the following serials are just for debugging
        Serial.println(ph_lvl);
        previousMillis = millis();
        if (ph_lvl == 2) {
            rtime = number - 20;
            digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(alkml, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(acidml, LOW);
            Serial.println(rtime * second);
            mtime = rtime * 1000;
            if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= mtime) {
                previousMillis = currentMillis;
                digitalWrite(alkml, LOW);
                digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
                digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
            }
        } else {
            digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
            digitalWrite(alkml, LOW);
        }
        if (ph_lvl == 1) {
            rtime = number - 10;
            mtime = rtime * 1000;
            digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(alkml, LOW);
            digitalWrite(acidml, HIGH);
            Serial.println(rtime);
            Serial.println(mtime);
            if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= mtime) {
                previousMillis = millis();
                digitalWrite(red, LOW);
                digitalWrite(acidml, LOW);
                digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
            }
        } else {
            digitalWrite(red, LOW);
            digitalWrite(acidml, LOW);
        }
        if (ph_lvl == 0) {
            digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
            digitalWrite(red, LOW);
            digitalWrite(alkml, LOW);
            digitalWrite(acidml, LOW);
        } else {
            digitalWrite(green, LOW);
        }

        //this is old stuff, just for poc to get the hardware working
        if (number == 1) {
          digitalWrite(green, LOW);
          digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
          digitalWrite(red, LOW);
        }
        if (number == 7) {
          digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(alkml, LOW);
          digitalWrite(acidml, LOW);
        } else {
          digitalWrite(green, LOW);
        }
        if (number == 6) {
           digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(alkml, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(acidml, LOW);
        } else {
          digitalWrite(blue, LOW);
        }
        if (number == 8) {
           digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(alkml, LOW);
           digitalWrite(acidml, HIGH);
        } else {
           digitalWrite(red, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the raspi sends a number like, 25. which means dispense alkaline for 5 seconds. This parses correctly, but the motor just keeps running indefinitely. (There is some code that's commented out which works perfectly.)

How do I get the motors to run for a set amount of time withing the if statements? (Just a note, If the if statements are a bad thing to do and there's a better way to code what I'm trying to do, I'd gladly rewrite the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your time checking code in the wrong place. `receiveData()` is called only when some new data arrive, so a condition  `if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= mtime)` is evaluated only then. Leave rtime/mtime assignment where it is, but move stopping motors to `loop()`

Also, check out this example: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay

Comment: thanks, that makes tons of sense. its now working as intended.